# MySQL add prefix to table - WHERE syntax trouble

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a prefix `myprefix_` to MySQL table named `post`. I got stuck in one place:

```
DELETE FROM `post` WHERE `post`.`post_id` = ?
```

---

I added `myprefix_` here:

```
DELETE FROM `myprefix_post`
```

but what about second part?

```
WHERE `post`.`post_id` = ?
```

Should I change it to this?

```
WHERE `myprefix_post`.`post_id` = ?
```

---

W3Schools [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) gives an information that the syntax looks like this and I'm lost, because "post" is current table name:

```
FROM table_name WHERE condition;
```

Comment: If you're deleting from `myprefix_post` then `post` is most definitely NOT the current table name.

Comment: Why not just use `DELETE FROM myprefix_post WHERE post_id = ?`?

Comment: @JakubMuda No, that query makes no sense. Your use of `post` is to qualify the field `post_id` better, by specifying which table used in the query (FROM) that it is a part of. `post` is not used in the FROM, nor an alias of something used in the from, so cannot be used in the WHERE. If you are performing a simple delete from `myprefix_post`, you can only reference fields in `myprefix_post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an alias to the table name, then use the alias in the rest of the query.

```
DELETE FROM post AS p
WHERE p.post_id = ?
```

Then you can change the table name, but the rest of the query can continue to refer to it by the alias, so nothing else needs to change:

```
DELETE FROM myprefix_post AS p
WHERE p.post_id = ?
```

Otherwise, you'll need to change the table name prefix everywhere it appears:

```
DELETE FROM myprefix_post
WHERE myprefix_post.post_id = ?
```